# Cell vertically centered

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Is there a simple way to center the cell that contains "Q (2)" vertically?

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,addpoints,cancelspace]{exam}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{censor}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex

\begin{document}
\noindent


        \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{center}
        \scriptsize
        \label{1}
        \scriptsize
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.7\textwidth}|
                                      >{\centering\arraybackslash}wc{0.1\textwidth}|
                                      >{\centering\arraybackslash}wc{0.1\textwidth}|
                                      }
                                      \hline
            Title &Something &Something \\ \hline
            \hline
                          
            2. Apply the concepts of basic vector spaces topics to Rn and to the solution spaces of the ordinary
differential equations. & Q (2) &  \\ \hline
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
        \vspace{-0.5em}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you load the `array` package, you may achieve your formatting objective by replacing the `p` column type with the `m` column type for column 1.

Whatever else you may choose do, please replace `>{\centering\arraybackslash}wc{0.1\textwidth}` with `w{c}{0.1\textwidth}`. Put differently, please drop the `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` "prefix" of sorts.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,addpoints,cancelspace]{exam}
\usepackage{array,amssymb}
\usepackage{censor}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex

\begin{document}
%\noindentn% redundant

\begin{table}[h]
        \centering % use "\centering" rather than a "center" environment
        \scriptsize
        %\label{1} "\label" doesn't have desired effect unless preceded by "\caption" 
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
        \begin{tabular}{|m{0.7\textwidth}|  % <-- use 'm', not 'p', col. type
                         w{c}{0.1\textwidth}|
                         w{c}{0.1\textwidth}|
                       }
             \hline
             Title & Something & Something \\ 
             \hline\hline
                          
            2. Apply the concepts of basic vector spaces topics 
               to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and to the solution spaces of 
               the ordinary differential equations. & 
            Q (2) &  \\ 
            \hline\hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Another way to achieve the desired vertical centering -- other than to use an explicit `m` column type rather than a `p` column type -- is to employ a `tabularx` environment and to run the instruction `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`. This works because the `X` column type defined by the `tabularx` package *is* is `p`-column with a "twist" -- the fact that LaTeX calculates its width automatically, as a residual.

For the following screenshot, I've done away with the `\scriptsize` directive (mainly because I don't understand its purpose) and replaced both instances of `w{c}{0.1\textwidth}` with `c`. The upper `tabularx` environment continues the baroque look with lots of vertical and horizontal rules; the lower `tabularx` environment removes a lot of that cruft by doing away with all vertical rules and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,addpoints,cancelspace]{exam}
\usepackage{array,amssymb}
\usepackage{censor}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % for vertical centering
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
   %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
   \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|c|c|}
      \hline
      Title & Something & Something \\ 
      \hline\hline
      2. Apply the concepts of basic vector spaces topics 
         to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and to the solution spaces of 
         the ordinary differential equations. 
      & Q (2) &  \\ 
      \hline\hline
   \end{tabularx}

   \vspace{1cm}
   % same structure, but without any vertical rules, and with fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} Lcc @{}}
      \toprule
      Title & Something & Something \\ 
      \midrule
      2. Apply the concepts of basic vector spaces topics 
         to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and to the solution spaces of 
         the ordinary differential equations. 
      & Q (2) &  \\ 
      \bottomrule
   \end{tabularx}   

\end{table}
\end{document}
```